# Why is a blob url not found (404), when it has a fragment identifier in Safari?

Tags: javascript, url, safari, blob

It appears that Safari does not recognize a URL created with [URL.createObjectURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) that contains an anchor on the end of the URL. When there is no anchor, it works fine, but it is a requirement to have the anchor as I am working with SVG's. The code in this question has been isolated to show the issue.

**NOTE: This is only an issue in Safari.** Chrome and Firefox work fine.

Here is an example of creating a blob URL:

```
var blob = new Blob([
    `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <rect id="rect" fill="black" width="20" height="20"></rect>
    </svg>`
], {type: 'image/svg+xml'});

var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob) + '#rect';

$.get(url).done(function (res) { console.log(res) });
```

The above code creates a URL that is formatted like the following:

```
blob:http://localhost/e060d31f-6eb0-4565-890d-6de601efcc3e#rect
```

But when I try to get the contents of it, I get a 404 (Not Found) error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

---

Here is the part that doesn't make sense to me, if I remove the anchor from the URL:

```
// don't use an anchor
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

Then it works just fine, and get the contents of the "URL".

---

Since the "anchor" is part of a standard URL, it does not need to be encoded.

I did find a [logged bug](https://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-unassigned/2016-April/711987.html) that sounds like it could be the same problem. It has to do with query params, and not anchor tags. Is there some way that I can get this to work now? Or is this something that will have to wait until the related bug gets fixed?

Comment: It's almost a decade later, and having hashes at the end of blobs is still an issue, even on the newest iOS. I tripped over it today. I need to abandon using media fragments on blobs for this. I can not answer as for why they dont fix this, though.