# audio Blob not working in IOS / Safari

Tags: ios, node.js, socket.io, blob, html5-audio

I am recording audio, sending it as a blob to a nodejs server. The nodejs server then sends it to all connected users that are not currently recording.

**Sending the blob:**

```
mediaRecorder.onstop = function(e) {
  var blob = new Blob(this.chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' });
  socket.emit('radio', blob);
};
```

**Server receiving the blob:**

```
socket.on('radio', function(blob) {
  socket.broadcast.emit('voice', blob);
});
```

**Listener receiving the blob:**

```
socket.on('voice', function(arrayBuffer) {
  var blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], { 'type' : 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' });
  var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
  audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  audio.play();
});
```

This works in all browsers/devices except safari and any ios device.  Taking it further with safari's inspector I found this:

[image: 1st blob object returned]
[image: 2nd blob object returned]
[image: 3rd blob object returned]

Does safari require something else in its headers for blob objects to be interpreted properly? I've researched accepted audio types, tried aac/mp3/ogg without any success. Upon reading further I've heard references to the fact that there is a bug with streaming blob audio/video data in safari and IOS though I'm not too clear any the details.

Guidance in the rite direction would be very helpful!

**EDIT:** It looks like this line `audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);` in the receiving blob is what is causing the blob errors (image i linked)

**EDIT 2:** I tried to see if using another format other than blob would work, opting for base64 encoded string. Looks like this works on all devices and browsers except for IOS and Safari. I'm getting the impression it has something to do with how IOS interprets/loads the data...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: This should work now, see this answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56330664/2196424

Answer (score 3):

For me the solution was to insert a source element into the audio element, and use the sourceElement.src attribute to refer to the blob. I didn't even need to attach the audio-element to the DOM. Example below, hope it helps someone.

```
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio')
var sourceElement = document.createElement('source')

audioElement.appendChild(sourceElement)

sourceElement.src = '<your blob url>'
sourceElement.type = 'audio/mp3' // or whatever

audioElement.load()

audioElement.play()
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't been able to find a solution using an audio element, however the Web Audio Api seems to do the trick:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API

```
    var audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext);
    socket.on('voice', function(arrayBuffer) {
      audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer, audioData => {
        var source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
        source.buffer = audioData;
        source.connect(audioContext.destination);
        source.start()
    });
```

You may still have an issue on iOS as any audio/video must be triggered by a user action.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem this week. I was recording the audio on Safari and the audio blob was being generated just fine. But when I tried to send the blob to server, no data was getting there. The solution bellow reads the blob with File Reader to convert it to base64, and afterwards send it to server. Here is what worked for me:

```
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(audioBlob);
      reader.onloadend = () => {
      const base64data = reader.result;

      const audioName = uuid.v4() + '.mp3';
      this.http.post(this.app.cloudStorageEndpoint + '/audios/local?audioName=' + audioName, base64data , header).subscribe(
        res => { resolve(audioName); },
        err => { reject(err); }
      );
  };
```

I've tested with Safari 12 on both iPad and iPhone and it worked fine.

Comment: This issue is a little different. I was able to send the data back to the server, but when sending it to other connected clients, they were unable to receive the data on iOS and safari